ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.main' after correcting setup.py (Python package entry point)
I'm facing a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.main' when trying to run my script treev in a Python package. I've made sure the setup.py has the correct entry point configuration (entry_points={'console_scripts': ['treev = test.main:main']}).
The directory structure is as follows:
.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── reinstall.sh
├── setup.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main.py

My setup.py file contents:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my_package',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'treev = test.main:main'  # Corrected path: 'test.main' directly refers to main.py
        ]
    },
    description='A short description of your package',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    author='anchalshivank',
    author_email='your@email.com',
    url='https://github.com/yourusername/my_package',
    license='MIT',
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
    ],
)



I'm using a virtual environment and running treev from the package directory. I've tried reinstalling the package (pip install .) but the error persists.
Any suggestions on resolving this issue or diagnosing the cause further would be greatly appreciated!
